# What is an example of a vector law which is not covariant under Lorentz transformations?

Tags: special-relativity, spacetime, covariance

I'm currently studying relativity and the covariant formalism. From what I understood the main reason why this formalism has been introduced is because in this way the laws of physics are covariant under the Lorentz transformations, which are the correct transformations of space and time coordinates.

Now I'd like to have an example of a vector law which is not covariant under Lorentz transformations if written in the 3D-vector formalism and which is instead covariant under the 4D-vector one.

Comment: I assume that when you say *covariant* you actually mean *manifestly covariant*. If this is it, then Newton's third law $F=ma$ is not, manifestly, covariant. In it's $4$-vector counterpart $\mathcal{F}^\mu = m\frac{du^\mu}{d\tau}$ is

Comment: @DavideMorgante Well, to prevent confusion, $F=ma$ is neither manifestly covariant (written in 4-vector notation) _nor_ covariant in the ordinary sense (remains true after a Lorentz transformation).

Comment: @knzhou Yes, that's also true.

Answer (score 2):

Probably the simplest example of this is the first vector law you ever learned,
$$\mathbf{F} = m \mathbf{a}.$$
If you define these quantities in the usual way, 
$$\mathbf{F} = \frac{d\mathbf{p}}{dt}, \quad \mathbf{a} = \frac{d \mathbf{v}}{dt}$$
then this equation is simply not true in special relativity. It's not even true if you artificially allow the coefficient $m$ to vary, because in situations where the force is not parallel to the velocity, the force and the acceleration aren't even parallel!

Instead, in special relativity you use the four-vector equation
$$f^\mu = m a^\mu$$
where the quantities are defined as 
$$f^\mu = \frac{dp^\mu}{d\tau}, \quad a^\mu = \frac{du^\mu}{d\tau}$$
where $\tau$ is the proper time and $u^\mu = dx^\mu/d\tau$ is the four-velocity. This is a four-vector equation that reduces to $\mathbf{F} = m \mathbf{a}$ at low velocities, but which is true in general.

Comment: Alright, but what I'd like to see is explicitly why it's not covariant. How can I do that?

Comment: @A.J. Well, first off, can you define what you mean by "covariant"?

Comment: I mean Lorentz covariant

Comment: @A.J. Well, what exactly do you mean by Lorentz covariant?

Comment: I mean that if in a frame of reference I have F=ma then under the Lorentz transformations I have F' = ma' in another frame.

Answer (score 2):

The notation or formalism used to express a physical law doesn’t affect whether that law is covariant under some group of transformations. Maxwell’s equations, for example, are covariant under Lorentz transformations whether written in terms of $\mathbf{E}$ and $\mathbf{B}$ or in terms of $F^{\mu\nu}$.

But using Lorentz four-vectors and four-tensors makes a law *obviously* (or “manifestly”) Lorentz-covariant because of their simple Lorentz transformation properties, in the same way that three-vector equations are manifestly covariant under Euclidean rotations.

It is *not* obvious that Maxwell’s equations are Lorentz-covariant when written in terms of $\mathbf{E}$ and $\mathbf{B}$, but it *is* when they are written in terms of $F^{\mu\nu}$.

The formalism of Lorentz four-vectors and four-tensors actually makes it impossible to write laws which are *not* Lorentz-covariant, when you respect the rules of the formalism.

Comment: Ok so what you are saying is that if a law written is the index notation is manifestly covariant then it’s 3D components will be as well.

Comment: The only doubt I have is this then: why do you say that it’s not obvious if a law written in 3D vector form is covariant under Lorentz transformation or not?

Comment: I can’t figure out what you are asking in your first comment because I don’t know whether you are talking about covariance of the 3D components under Lorentz transformations or under rotations.

Comment: Lorentz transformations

Comment: In that case, your first comment misunderstood me. You can’t take 3 out of 4 components of a Lorentz-covariant equation and have them still be Lorentz-covariant, because Lorentz transformations mix all four components together.

Comment: *why do you say that it’s not obvious if a law written in 3D vector form is covariant under Lorentz transformation or not?* Try performing a Lorentz transformation on Maxwell’s equations written using three-vectors. The transformation of the spatial divergences and curls, and the time derivatives, is complicated. And it isn’t obvious at all how the field vectors should transform under a boost, in order to keep the form of the equations the same. It can be done, but it is far from obvious.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/106326/discussion-between-a-j-and-g-smith).